# Cross Domain Messaging between different 'windows' in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, postmessage, window.opener

On my parent window, I have:

```
if (window.addEventListener){
    addEventListener("message", listener, false);
} else {
    attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
}
```

On the popup, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.postMessage("complete", "*");
    window.close();
</script>
```

This works for all the browsers except... yes you guessed it correct. IE-11!

Has anyone faced a similar problem before and can help me with fixing the existing code or giving an alternate solution? I have tried googling hard!

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar problem a few months ago while developing a framework designed for this sort of thing. Essentially, I gave up and instead had my parent window send a message to my child window (right after it was created), and that message contains the event source as part of the message (which is essentially a reference to the parent window). I then reply back to the window by doing postMessage on that object.